# How to redirect to a certain route after/at the time of sending response to the client side, in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am a beginner learner of Express.JS having issue in the redirecting of routes. All I want is to show a message to user that "Your data is registered successfully. " and then after a certain time period, i want to redirect them to form page again. But getting few errors in it.

This is a code where i am writing data in a text file and then after showing a message, i want to redirect to /form route.

```
router.use('/form',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("form is loaded ");
    res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir,'views','form.html'));
}); 



router.post('/submit',(req,res)=>{
    const data=()=>{
        const time=Date();
        const firstName=req.body.firstName;
        const lastName=req.body.LastName;
        const email= req.body.email;
        const address=req.body.address;
        const state=req.body.state;
        const phone= req.body.phone;
        const pinCode= req.body.pinCode;
        let data=time+"\n"+'    Name   --->    '+firstName+" "+lastName+'\n';
        data+='    E-mail   --->    '+email+'\n';
        data+='    Phone  --->    '+phone+'\n';
        data+='    Address  --->    '+address+'\n';
        data+='    State  --->    '+state+' - '+pinCode+'\n\n';
        return data;
    }
    // console.log(firstName,lastName,email,phone,address,state,pinCode);


    fs.appendFile(dbFile,data(),(error)=>{
        console.log("Data added to database");
    });

   
    res.send('Your data is registered successfully.');
    
    setInterval(()=>{res.redirect('/form');}, 3000);
});
```

I am getting following error in that case:

```
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: **Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:530:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/infogirdinformatics/Desktop/Nilesh/IG/Express.js/Day 15/Task 3/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
```

Please suggest me any way or solution. Thanks for the help and time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i got a clear understanding of Front end routing and Back-end Routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send an HTTP redirect after sending a response, so I would probably instead do:

```
res.send(`
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/form" />
    </head>
    <body>Your data is registered successfully.</body>
  </html>
`);
```

and use an [HTML Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#html_redirections)

Comment: But i have seen this redirecting in many websites, how they are going to do? Are they using the HTML redirect.

Comment: could be doing that, could be handling it with javascript on the frontend